# Role of istio-agent in the configuration of Envoy proxy belonging to a service mesh

Tags: kubernetes, service, istio, envoyproxy

Pilot uses ADS APIs to configure the Envoy proxy for each service or the configs are first pushed to the istio-agent and then mapped to the proxy.

I am unable to understand the role of istio-agent while configuring the proxies. The documentation does not provide sufficient information.

According to the documentation, the istio-agent run inside a pod and is used to requests certificates from citadel using an open gRPC connection. However, nothing is stated about proxy configurations and service discovery.